# How can I compute newest calcs efficiently(historical vol, correlation, etc)? [R]

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

I've mainly been working with historical financial data, but want to implement a system that appends a new price and efficiently computes the new variables for just that new addition. Currently using **`data.table`** to perform the aggregate calculations, but that causes a bit too much latency since it currently computes those variables for the entire time series.  Looking for any guidance on the subject. Thanks.

**Edit**
So effectively I want to compute the standard deviation of a time series at different lags.

The data looks like this:

```
DATE-         TIC    -  RET1
2018-02-21    AAPL    .04
2018-02-22    AAPL    .02
2018-02-23    AAPL   -.01
2018-02-21    GE      .04
2018-02-22    GE      .02
2018-02-23    GE     -.01
```

Currently I just make the `data` a `data.table`, order it, and use the TTR `runSD()` function:

```
data[,computed1 := runSD(`ret1`,2)* x, by = 'tic']
```

This will compute the 2day rolling standard deviation at every position, when I just want to compute it for the newest entries. ( Being the 2018-02-23 in the `data` sample )

Further explanation (I apologize for the redundancy)
Given my current code I will get the SD for 2018-02-22 and 2018-02-23.[23&22, 22&21] I only want output for 2018-02-23 entries though.

*2 day SD just for example purposes.

Comment: Typically questions on SO are about programming, including sample data and code attempted. There are certainly legitimate excursions from that theme, but this question seems a bit vague to answer. Also, please know that question asking to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"* are also often closed as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry if my form is a bit off. I didn't think my current code mattered since although it works, its too slow (and its basically just 1 line lol). I figured there were individuals experienced in this whom would know the answer from the description.

Comment: Understood, but realize that we have nothing to go with here, just a vague description of the process. SO is typically a very literal q/a site, so broad questions (without backing data and usually code) are discouraged. Sometimes, questions can come across as *"write this code for me for free"*, which often sparks quick backlash in the form of acerbic comments, downvotes, close-requests, etc. (Some of "us" need to grow thicker skins and perhaps learn some new patience, but ... there are a lot of new questioners who tend to abuse the system, knowingly or not.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. Does my edit make it any better?

Comment: Much better, though I'm still at a slight loss. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *"bit too much latency"* and why *"the entire timeseries"* is wrong. Your current dataset doesn't support lagging by 21, so perhaps you can provide *slightly* more data and demonstrate what is wrong with the results using a much lower lag (e.g., 3). Including "actual vs expected output" can go a long ways towards demonstrating the problem.

Comment: With all due respect, the problem **formulation is clear and sound**. This is a very common problem for latency-shaving in Quant-modelling and Time Series processing. If not proficient in this aspect, kindly do not punish @JohnDoe for asking it here.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested in the answer, accomplished this by storing data as a return stream. Date-Yaxis, ticker-Xaxis, data-1dayreturn.

Save as RData each day due to number of columns ~8k.

Save a snapshot from eod t-1. Compute T0 return vs T-1 eod snapshot. Format as return stream as stated above.

Pull the RData. Rbind current return to the historical return stream. Compute your calculations on this return stream. ie stdev, corr, cov , etc.

Should give you lower latency calcs (<10sec). Let me know if you know of a better way.